# How To Remember Form Data(sign-up form) when i click Back Button?

Tags: php, html

for you information i'm using `session_start();`.

Comment: no user input required here. The user should be given filled form already, without clicking any buttons

Answer (score 0):

Register each data on your submitted form into session variables, something like this:

```
foreach ($submitted_form as $key=>$val) {
  $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
}
```

When user callback the previous form, just echo those session variables in your expected element, something like this :

```
<input type="text" name="data[username]" value="<?= $_SESSION['username']" />
<input type="text" name="data[password]" value="<?= $_SESSION['password']" />
```

hope this helps.

Comment: That won't work when going back if the page has been cached, and by not using `htmlspecialchars`, you are opening up an XSS security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for session variables on the page your are redirected to when you press back.

consider login.php where you created a session and saved the form data,
and home.php is where you are redirected to when you press back..

so, make home.php to check and maintain the session variables throughout the session!

Answer (score -1):

you can use javascript for that.

```
   window.history.back()
```

or you can use `session variables` for that.

this is May be help you.

Thanks.